# Sorting not working in MYSQL if(inSortOrder='first_name',concat(A.first_name,'_A_',A.last_name),''),

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I'm very new to dynamic sql and have inherited a project that I can't seem to figure out.

Sorting has never worked correctly in this project, and I'm trying to figure it out while keeping the sql and stored procedure dynamic.

This line below is basically the problem.  IF the variable inSortOrder is 'first_name, then the sql should sort first by first_name and then by last name.

The problem is, I need to sort by ASC or DESC depending on another variable passed.

I have no idea what the *A* does and have not been able to find information about it on the internet.  I've tried adding another ' DESC' or ' ASC' but it's always ignored.

It always comes back Ascending no matter what.  Does anyone know how to fix this, and still sort by multiple fields?  What is the *A* do?

```
if(inSortOrder='first_name',concat(A.first_name,'_A_',A.last_name),''),
```

**EDIT:**
The entire stored procedure is over 100 lines long, but here is the query in question. I know the rest of it works. Just having a problem with sorting. Specifical, trying to figure out what the "*A*" does.(a between underscores)

Assume variable inOrder is put into stored procedure as 'first_name'.  Basically trying to figure out how to edit the last line, into sorting by DESC or ASC, depending on another variable.

SELECT
        A.first_name,

```
N.middle_name

    N.last_name
  FROM
      student S left JOIN
      names N on S.id = N.student_id
  WHERE
    N.record_status = 'FAILED'
```

ORDER BY
if(inOrder='first_name',concat(N.first_name,'*A*',N.last_name),''),

Comment: You'll need to post more code than that to get a good response.  What have you tried?

Comment: Please post your entire query (table structure, sample data and desired results would be nice).  It's difficult to understand what you're asking with the one if statement above.

Comment: What does ***which*** `A` do?  The `A.` in `A.first_name` or the `_A_` string between `first_name` and `last_name`?

Comment: And the _A_ string between the underscores. Instead of underscores, the _A_ above has italics.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. Like always, I just need to spend more time looking at the code when I'm unfamiliar with it.  New to dynamic sql but I like what I see so far.

It's done like this
Variables are 
inSortOrder = 'last_name'
inSortType = 'DESC'

```
    if(inOrder='last_name' and inType<>'DESC',concat(N.last_name,'_A_',N.first_name,'_A_',N.middle_name),''),
    if(inOrder='last_name' and inType='DESC',concat(N.last_name,'_A_',N.first_name,'_A_',N.middle_name),'') DESC,
```